# How to display a random object from an array in a an angular view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, random

I try to display information of a random object from an array into a NG-Repeat situation in my DOM :

So firs, here is the code of the controller that simply makes the array and fills it up of objects :

```
// We check the businesses in the 500m to display a random wide range ad
  // First we get the coordinates of the user
    database.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var lat50 = snapshot.val().lat;
    var long50 = snapshot.val().long;
    var rootRef50 = firebase.database().ref();
    var geoFireRef50 = rootRef50.child("geobusiness");
    var restaurantsRef50 = rootRef50.child("businessarround");
    var geoFire50 = new GeoFire(geoFireRef50);
    // Then we make a call for Geofire to check all businesses arround
    var geoQuery50 = geoFire50.query({
    center: [lat50, long50],
    radius: 0.5
  });
  // This is the array that contains the results below
  var matches50 = [];
  console.log(matches50);

  // Listen to every businesses in our query...
  geoQuery50.on("key_entered", function(key) {

    // ... and look them up by key ...
    restaurantsRef50.child(key).once("value", function(snapshot) {
      var restaurant50 = snapshot.val();
      matches50.push(restaurant50);
      for (var i = 0; i < matches50.length; i++)
    if (matches50[i].uid && matches50[i].uid === userId) {
        matches50.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
      $timeout(function(){
        //here we scope the array to write in our DOM
      $scope.businessAd = matches50;

      // Set a timeout to clear loader, however you would actually call the $ionicLoading.hide(); method whenever everything is ready or loaded.
      $timeout(function () {

        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }, 1000);

      })

    });
  });
```

The HTML code :

```
<div class="content2" ng-repeat="businessAd in businessAds" ng-controller="businessPageController">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="profile-info">
                <!-- *profile-image / image profile -->
                <img class="profile-image" src="img/100.jpg">
                <!-- *profile-name / name profile -->
                <h3 class="profile-name">{{businessAd.name}}</h3>
                <!-- *profile-description / description profile -->
                <span class="profile-description">
                    {{businessAd.description}}
                </span>
        <br /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
```

However, now, I would like to display them randomly because it is **not a list** but a single emplacement. Therefore, I would like to randomly display one of the objects from my array into that HTML code.

**Moreover**, I would like to make sure that if there is only ONE object in my array, it always displays it.

What to do ?

Comment: why not taking the first element

Comment: Well because it display the ads of businesses around in the 500m radius and I don't want to display the closest one, I want a random selection in these 500m. Especially because after I will have an option of "frequency" where some will appear multiple times in the array...

Comment: i`m not sure if this can work try using Javascript date object with getMilliseconds() then % array.length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need an ng-repeat here, since you only want to dispaly one item (or nothing if there are no items), so replace the ng-repeat with:

```
ng-if="businessAd"
```

You can put this in your controller to get a random add.

```
        //here we scope the array to write in our DOM
      var matches50Length = matches50.length;
      if(matches50Length > 0){
           // get random array index
           var random = matches50[Math.floor(Math.random()* matches50.length)];
           $scope.businessAd = random;
      }
```

Comment: Hello, it probably is on the right way but it doesn't display anything however there are objects being pushed in my array... Actually I have 2 objects to be pushed and both of them are being pushed in the array but doesn't display any of them...

Comment: Is this before you impliment the changes to the controller? If it is then: what is in $scope.businessAd[0].name and $scope.businessAd[0].description?

Comment: Well first, the console.log(random) fires 4 times, I don't know why, and then businessAd[0] of name and desc return : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. But the console.log(random) actually displays random data from the array, so it exists !

Comment: It looks like you made the changes to the controller, then. Did you?  So did you make this change to the view? ng-if="businessAd" replacing ng-repeat="businessAd in businessAds" ?

Comment: Yes I actually put it in the right place : <div class="profile-info" ng-if="businessAd">

Comment: If all the changes have been made, then check businessAd.name and businessAd.description. businessAd should now be a single object. What is in there?

Comment: Oh I found the mistake, I changed you $scope.businessAd = matches50[random]; by : $scope.businessAd = random; and now it works ! Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it ! I accept and upvote your initial answer !

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you can implement in your controller, the first thing that comes to mind is something like this

controller:

```
var matchLength = matches50.length;
var randInBound = Math.floor(Math.random() * matchLength) + 1;
$scope.matched = matches50[randInBound];
```

Then, from your html you should be able to access this object and display it, and it'll always give you a result as long as there's at least 1 item in your array

Comment: I don't think this will ever select matches50[0] and might fail when selecting matches50[1] if that is empty. I think Math.floor(Math.random() * matchLength) + 1 is always >=1

Comment: Thank you for your help, I actually found the other answer more appropriate for my situation ! I upvoted anyway !